# Can you be detected while invisible?

Tags: invisibility, cyberpunk-2020, netrunner

If I have *Invisibility* running and see a *Pitbull*, does it automatically fail to detect me, or do we still make opposed stealth/evasion rolls?

On the one hand, *Invisibility* says it "will allow the Netrunner to pass unnoticed through the Net." Plain reading: you're not detected. (Except by *SeeYa*, which specifically counters invisibility.)

On the other hand, that would mean that one of the least expensive (in cost and memory usage) programs moots all the defenses of any system not employing *SeeYa*. And why does *Invisibility* even need a strength, if not to pit against detection programs' strengths?

Comment: @CorvenDallas: [Don't answer in comments](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6533/should-users-refrain-from-answers-or-partial-answers-in-comments) (including partial or speculative answers).

Answer (score 1):

**Netrunning section: Stealth and Evasion** (page 152 core rulebook)

A program can attack anything that can see. The programs don't have front or rear side, so they can see you coming ever and in any direction.

These is where stealth and evasion come in.  When you use a program of **Stealth or Invisibility** the oponnet must roll to see if can sense your presence

STR attack prog. + 1D10 vs STR. your program + 1D10

**NOTE**: Translated from spanish without the flavour text.

So its clearly and specifically noted that **any program** vs an **Invisibility** program any other program checks to notice your presence.

Comment: I posted an image of the section of the book, but it doesn't appear on the answer